# Go doesn't find /usr/share/zoneinfo in docker container

Tags: go, alpine-linux, zoneinfo

In a Go program I call `time.LoadLocation("Europe/Berlin")` and it returns an error saying `open /usr/local/go/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip: no such file or directory`, even though in the container (running `alpine:3.9` with tzdata installed) `/usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Berlin` exists and, according to the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#LoadLocation), should take precedence over the zip file. The same program finds the file on my machine (Arch Linux). The executable got statically linked on my machine and then copied into the container. I tried Go 1.11.5 and 1.10.3.

I built the executable with:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -a -ldflags "-s" -o gocake_static
```

I'm looking for any ideas that help me identify the problem.

Comment: Did you specify the container's os and arch when you build that executable? Can you share the command with which you build the executable?

Comment: ... is the `ZONEINFO` env variable set on the container, and if so what is its value?

Comment: @mkopriva No, I didn't. It should be the same architecture, though, no? I added the build command to my question.

Comment: @mkopriva Setting the `ZONEINFO` variable doesn't seem to make a difference. I tried setting it to `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

Comment: Is the `tzdata` package installed? (In the official Ubuntu images it is not).

Comment: @kostix Yes it is.

Comment: Please see how the Go runtime [looks for the timezone info](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/35bb62e60a7779ff82c3067903b3306ff8666471/src/time/zoneinfo.go#L269) (for 1.11.5); [here](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/35bb62e60a7779ff82c3067903b3306ff8666471/src/time/zoneinfo_unix.go#L19) is where the locations are on UNIX-compatibles. Basically, it appears that the idea of Alpine Linux about where the tzdata is located is different from that of the Go stdlib.

Comment: What you're seeing is the failure of the stdlib code to find the tzdata in any of the known built-in locations, so the last-resort one, which attempts to find a zip archive with the tzdata in the root directory of the Go installation, fails, and is shown.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem under `go:1.11.5` and `alpine:3.9` with `tzdata` installed. I built the binary ( `GOOS=linux` `GOARCH=amd64` `CGO_ENABLED=0` ) in Mac and put it in an alpine container. I didn't set `ZONEINFO` variable. Are there other env variables may cause the problem?

Answer (score 1):

if you use only one static zoneinfo. maybe `FixedZone` can solve your problem.

It does not require timezone.zip, thus no need to download `zoneinfo.zip` and set env `ZONEINFO` in Dockerfile.

for example

```
loc := time.FixedZone("Europe/Berlin", 1*60*60)
fmt.Println(time.Now().In(loc).Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
```